# Where is samba-dbg for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, samba

I have a lot of `samba panic` lately.  According to the mails I receive, I should install the package `samba-dbg`to file a bug in launchpad.
So, I try to install it but apt does not find it:

```
sudo apt-get install samba-dbg
...
E: Unable to find the package samba-db
```

According to this [list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=samba), `samba-dbg`does not exist for Ubnutu 18.04.  Could someone confirm or indicate what to do in such a case?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install samba-dbgsym`.

Comment: @LewisSmith: same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages#Getting_-dbgsym.ddeb_packages has the information you need.

Comment: Thank you it helps forward.  However, now ,I get:`sudo apt-get install samba-dbgsym
...Some packages could not be installed. ...
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba-dbgsym : Depends: samba (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.6) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: it's because that wiki page instructed to add the proposed pocket, I'm not sure why. Edit the file you created and remove the line that mentions proposed and retry.